# container instantiation not working

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to get all records from a table in a test function.
calling `DB::table('degrees')->get()` returns all the expected values,
But trying to run the following code returns an empty collection:

```
$db = $this->app->make('db');
$db->connection('testing');
$db->table('degrees')->get();
```

The only problem I can think of is that, project is not configured correctly.

my phpunit.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <phpunit backupGlobals="false"
     backupStaticAttributes="false"
     bootstrap="bootstrap/autoload.php"
     colors="true"
     convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
     convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
     convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
     processIsolation="false"
     stopOnFailure="false">
  <testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Feature">
        <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Feature</directory>
  </testsuite>

  <testsuite name="Unit">
        <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit</directory>
    </testsuite>
  </testsuites>
  <filter>
    <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
        <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
    </whitelist>
  </filter>
  <php>
    <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
    <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
  </php>
</phpunit>
```

my `createApplication` function:

```
/**
 * Creates the application.
 *
 * @return Application
 */
public function createApplication(): Application
{
    $app = require __DIR__ . '/../bootstrap/app.php';
    $app->make(Kernel::class)->bootstrap();
    return $app;
}
```

my database configuration for `.env.testing`

```
DB_CONNECTION=testing
DB_HOST=192.168.70.10
DB_DATABASE=testing
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

`database.php` file

```
'testing' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'testing'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'homestead'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ]
```

I can confirm that there is data in table by calling `Degree::all()` or `DB::table('degrees')->get()` but calling

```
$db=$this->app->make('db');
$db->connection('testing');
$db->table('degrees')->get();
```

returns empty `Collection`.

Laravel: `5.4.0`,
PhpUnit: `5.7.21`

Comment: just use createApplication trait in your test class, and call that function createApplication, now all Application initialized and you can access your data through db Facade:  if you wish to use another connection for testing connection , then disconnect default connection and use testing connection as =>  
 DB::disconnect('mysql');
        Config::set('database.connections.mysql.database', "test_db");

Comment: As far as I know, createApplication itself is called before every test is run (in setup method).  I think you didn't read my question throughoutly, I can get data with db fecade, the thing I can't accomplish is accessing data from the db insantiated from app->make method.